# responseXML is returning null?

Tags: ajax, xml

In my ajax call responseXML is returning null.Can anybody help me where did i do wrong?my code is.I checked my code.But I couldn't find any mistake.

```
function generateTable()
    {
        //alert("generating table");
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("get","data.xml",true);
        //xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(xhr.readyState == 4)
            {
                var root = xhr.responseXML;
                alert(root);
            }
        }
        xhr.send("");
    }
```

and my xml file is...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <temp_det>
        <srl_no>1</srl_no>
        <temperature>39</temperature>
        <on_or_off>on</on_or_off>
        <accuracy>87</accuracy>
    </temp_det>
    <temp_det>
       <srl_no>2</srl_no>
       <temperature>45</temperature>
       <on_or_off>off</on_or_off>
       <accuracy>67</accuracy>
   </temp_det>
   <temp_det>
       <srl_no>3</srl_no>
       <temperature>38</temperature>
       <on_or_off>on</on_or_off>
       <accuracy>78</accuracy>
   </temp_det>
</data>
```

Comment: your opening `data` tag is missing the opening bracket. Are you sure that this is not the case in your actual XML as well?

Comment: in my xml file data tag has opening bracket.it is fine

Comment: What about the url of the file that you are requesting? Ensure that requestUrl is correct and the file is at the right path.

Comment: my html file and xml file are in same folder

Comment: alert(xhr.responseText) is empty

Comment: Have you tried debugging this using the browser's developer tools? You'll find your error there.

Comment: it is giving this error."Failed to load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/xml/data2.xml: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
generateTable @ table.html:22
onclick @ table.html:28"

Answer (score 0):

> it is giving this error."Failed to load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/xml/data2.xml: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https

You are getting this error because Google Chrome does not allow you to access files via AJAX requests due to security reasons. So you have two options.

First, use `--allow-file-access-from-files` option and launch the browser through command prompt by following the below steps taken from [here](http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/windows.html). (Assuming you are on a Windows machine).

1. Get the url of your Chrome Installation path to your chrome installation e.g C:\Users-your-user-name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application>
2. Launch the Google Chrome browser from the command line window with the additional argument ‘–allow-file-access-from-files’. E.g ‘path to your chrome installation\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files’

Second, would be to install a web server. You must already have IIS on your machine. (Again, assuming you are using a Windows machine.) Request for the file via this server.

What you should note here is that Google Chrome is blocking such requests for a purpose. So it is advised that you skip the first option and opt for the second.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the first line of your XML file. 
I had the same problem and then i just took the first line of XML example in https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ and change it to my xml file.